# Check with code if FinalBuilder is running a script

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, finalbuilder

Is it possible to check if FinalBuilder is running a script with code?

I would like to make a small application that can remotely start building a project on a remote machine, but only if its not running a script already.

regards,
-Vegar

Comment: Maybe a tool like http://www.finalbuilder.com/finalbuilder-server.aspx or the free http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET;jsessionid=720FFB4E3A1CEDCADF03CDAFA5AA0C5B is something for you

Answer (score 1):

I can second Lars' recommendation of [FinalBuilder Server](http://www.finalbuilder.com/finalbuilder-server.aspx).  It allows you to launch and view the build progress through your webbrowser, and a single-user license is included with FinalBuilder Pro licenses, so you may already be covered.

I couldn't find any information on "Is running" in general, but if you're only interested in a single build script you could have the script create a "lock" file at the start and delete it at the end.  The launcher app would just check if that file exists.

Comment: For some reason, I was not aware of FinalBuilder Server. We will soon upgrade to FinalBuilder 6, a site license on FinalBuilder 6 Pro is  already paid for. As far as I can see, a FinalBuilder Server license is included in FinalBuilder Pro, so we should have all we need, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could always modify your final builder projects to write to an ini (or text file) when it starts, and delete the file when it completes.  I would suggest the name of the project.  That way if the file exists, then its busy compiling, and you can test to see what its compiling.